# Which exception should be thrown, when Spring SecurityContextHolder returns null on getPrincipal?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security

Which exception is best suited to describe the lack of Spring Security Principal in RESTful design, for example, when I get `null` while getting the Principal from `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()`?

I have a project with custom authorization service, and one part of it needs information about the Principal which is logged in and which authorities does he have.

Some (but not all) REST endpoints are also secured by Spring Security.

However the system grows larger and larger and a bug may happen, that unauthorized user will pass through the Controller layer, and will attempt to get access to the protected data by custom authorization service.

On the one hand, the best-suited exception seems to be `AccessDeniedException` (Http 403), but on the other hand it might be a more secure approach to throw 500 or 404 to "hide" the existence of the requested resource.

I thought about the following exceptions:

- HttpStatus: 500 caused by `org.springframework.security.access.AuthorizationServiceException`
- HttpStatus: 403 `org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException`
- HttpStatus: 500 `caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException`
- HttpStatus: 500 `caused by java.lang.NullPointerException`

I am not convinced which approach is better - to forbid, to hide or to throw internal server error.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring Security and a custom authorization service, you probably have something like this:

```
@Component
public class CustomAccessDeniedHandler extends AccessDeniedHandlerImpl {
    private final String HOME_PAGE = "/index.html";

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AccessDeniedException e) throws IOException, ServletException {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if (auth != null) {

            if (auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) {
                response.sendRedirect("/#/login");
                super.handle(request, response, e);
                return;
            }

            if (auth.getAuthorities().iterator().next().getAuthority().equals("ROLE_EMPLOYEE") || auth.getAuthorities().iterator().next().getAuthority().equals("ROLE_ADMIN") ) {
                 response.sendRedirect("/dashboard/Dashboard.xhtml");
                 super.handle(request, response, e);
                 return;
            }     
             response.sendRedirect("/#/dashboard/user");        
        }
        super.handle(request, response, e);
    }
}
```

In your case, in an application, I would rather suggest a redirect to the login screen -as shown above-, with a message like `Please log in`.

In an API, I would return a `404 - Resource not found` response.

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't mentioned, that several REST endpoints are not protected, eg. they have Spring Security permitAll() on them. My great concern is that it might happen, that a developer will return sensitive data working on another non-protected REST endpoint. That's why I introduced another layer of security. So your first answer with redirecting to the login page will not apply to my solution.

Comment: And the second part of your answer: can you elaborate, why would you pick 404 response? Do you refer to some industry standard?